# Query with pivot table laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

Query with pivot table laravel

Mappings

[image]

I am having a trouble with pivot query.

App/Entities/user.php

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\UserRole', 'user_user_roles', 'user_id', 'user_role_id');
}


public function getPivotCondition($roleId)
{
    return $this->roles()->wherePivot('user_role_id','=',$roleId);
}
```

Controller

```
    use App/Entities/user; 

    public function getUserWithRole(user $User){

    $users = $User->getPivotCondition(1)->get();

    dd($users);

    }
```

It results in a query

```
    SELECT `user_roles`.*, 
       `user_user_roles`.`user_id`      AS `pivot_user_id`, 
       `user_user_roles`.`user_role_id` AS `pivot_user_role_id` 
FROM   `user_roles` 
       INNER JOIN `user_user_roles` 
               ON `user_roles`.`id` = `user_user_roles`.`user_role_id` 
WHERE  `user_user_roles`.`user_id` IS NULL 
       AND `user_user_roles`.`user_role_id` = '1'
```

my question is that why i am getting **`user_user_roles`.`user_id` is null** in my query

I know that i can use **WhereHas** but i am looking for an alternative.I can use **wherePivot('user_role_id','=',$roleId,'or');** else **orWherePivot** but it will result in query condition to **or**.

Comment: What is `$User` in `$User->getPivotCondition(1)->get();`?

Comment: it is user model.Updated the code